# Convert string data in HDF5 File to float Format

Tags: type-conversion, python-3.6, hdf5

I need to convert String data from a HDF5 File to Float format to use in a Skyplot (Astropy) with l b coordinates. The data is present here:
[https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/~ensslin/research/data/faraday2020.html](https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/%7Eensslin/research/data/faraday2020.html)
(Faraday Sky 2020)

The code I have programmed until now is:

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import h5py

dat = []

ggl=[]

ggb=[]

f1= h5py.File('/home/nikita/faraday_2020/faraday2020.hdf5','r')
data = f1.get('faraday_sky_mean')
faraday_sky_mean = np.array(data)
data1 = f1.get('faraday_sky_std')
faraday_sky_std = np.array(data1)

n1 = 0
for line in f1:
   s = line.split()
   dat.append(s)
   n1 = n1 +1  
 #
for i in range(0,n1):
   ggl.append(float(dat[i][0])) # galactic coordinates input
   ggb.append(float(dat[i][1]))
 
f1.close()
```

However I am getting the error:

```
ggl.append(float(dat[i][0])) # galactic coordinates input

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'faraday_sky_mean'
```

Please help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting mean and standard dev values on skyplot using astropy grom hdf5 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67320825/plotting-mean-and-standard-dev-values-on-skyplot-using-astropy-grom-hdf5-file)

Answer (score 0):

What what you asked and what (I think) you need are 2 different things.
This line is NOT the way to read a HDF5 file: `for line in f1:`
You need to use a HDF5 API to read it (h5py is 1 of many).

I think you want to read datasets `faraday_sky_mean` and `faraday_sky_std` and load arrays into lists `ggl` and `ggb`. To do that, use this code. It will create 2 lists with 3145728 float64 values in each.

```
with h5py.File('faraday2020.hdf5','r') as hdf:
    print(list(hdf.keys()))
    faraday_sky_mean = hdf['faraday_sky_mean'][:]
    faraday_sky_std = hdf['faraday_sky_std'][:]
    
print(faraday_sky_mean.shape, faraday_sky_mean.dtype) 
print(f'Max Mean={max(faraday_sky_mean)}, Min Mean={min(faraday_sky_mean)}') 
print(faraday_sky_std.shape, faraday_sky_std.dtype) 
print(f'Max StdDev={max(faraday_sky_std)}, Min StdDev={min(faraday_sky_std)}') 

ggl = faraday_sky_mean.tolist()
print(len(ggl),type(ggl[0]))
ggb = faraday_sky_std.tolist()
print(len(ggb),type(ggb[0]))
```

The procedure above saves the data as both NumPy arrays and Python lists. If you only need the lists (don't need the arrays), you can shorten the code as shown below:

```
with h5py.File('faraday2020.hdf5','r') as hdf:
    ggl = hdf['faraday_sky_mean'][:].tolist()
    print(len(ggl),type(ggl[0]))
    ggb = hdf['faraday_sky_std'][:].tolist()
    print(len(ggb),type(ggb[0]))
```

Comment: thank you for your response. The issue I am facing is that the data present is in form of float64, which I want to load into ggl and ggb (pointed by you correctly). Further after this, I want to convert each of the float values to galactic coordinates (l and b) for which I am using astropy command
gl = ggl * u.degree
gb = ggb * u.degree
c = SkyCoord(l=gl,b=gb, frame='galactic', unit = (u.deg, u.deg)) #, 
l_rad = c.l.wrap_at(180 * u.deg).radian
b_rad = c.b.radian
However I am getting the error